# Covariance of square root of random variables

Tags: covariance, moments

Suppose I have the following expressions, where $X_1$,$X_2$,$Y$,$Z_1$,$Z_2$ are all random variables.

$$X_1^2 = B_1 Y + B_{Z_1} Z_1$$
$$X_2^2 = B_2 Y + B_{Z_2} Z_2$$

I'm interested in $Cov(X_1,X_2)$.

If I didn't have the square in the initial equations, you could use linearity and break it down into weighted products of the covariances between $Y$,$Z_1$,$Z_2$. With the square I'm at a loss for how to proceed. Is there a closed form solution? What if I made the simplifying assumption that $Y$,$Z_1$,$Z_2$ were Gaussian?

Any advice as to how to proceed is appreciated.

Comment: What if $B_!Y +B_{Z_1}Z_1$ is negative? Is $X_1$ then a _complex-valued_ random variable? This would _certainly_ occur if you make the simplifying assumption that $Y, Z_1, Z_2$ are normal random variables.

Comment: Even if you make $B_1Y +B_{Z_1}Z_1\geq 0$ (etc), I don't think it's determined, since $X^2 = (-X)^2$ and in general $\text{Cov}(-X_1,X_2) \neq \text{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$. If this is a real problem you're leaving some important information out, and if it's not you need to think about the conditions you want with some care.

Comment: This is ugly with so many subscripts — you could instead ask about the covariance of $U=\sqrt{aX+bY}$ and $V=\sqrt{cX+dZ}$.